# Php Form not capturing values of dynamic fields

Tags: php, jquery

i have a form to be used to make orders for eggs.In this i have a button that  creates dynamically a form group where users can enter more orders. That worked perfectly well.
However, i'm trying to collect and display the information from the dynamically generated form groups (as a test during development before inserting into the dB) but that isn't working. Only **one** information from the original form (not dynamic) displays. 
Any assistance to resolve this will be appreciated.
Here are my php and jquery scripts. First php;
NB: please note i haven't sanitized my scripts yet here. Will surely do so.

```
<?php
    require("includes/conn.php");
    $message = '';
    if (isset($_POST['order_submit'])){
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        $quant = $_POST['quant'];
        $client_name = $_POST['client_name'];
        $client_add= $_POST['client_add'];
        $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];

        foreach($type AS $key=>$value){//echo out on the screen the entered values in the dynamic fields only returns the value entered into one field 
            echo $value;
        }
    }
?>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" id="order_eggs">
   <div class="orders_details">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="type" class="col-md-2 control-label">Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select name="type[]" class="form-control type">
               <option value="">-- Select Type of Eggs --</option>
               <option value="wsmall">White Small (N550 per crate)</option>
               <option value="wmedium">White Medium (N620 per crate)</option>
               <option value="wjumbo">White Jumbo (N750 per crate)</option>
               <option value="bsmall">Brown Small (N530 per crate)</option>
               <option value="bmedium">Brown Medium (N600 per crate)</option>
               <option value="bjumbo">Brown Jumbo (N700 per crate)</option>
           </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="quant" class="col-md-2 control-label">Quantity(Crates)</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control quant" name="quant[]" placeholder="Quantity of eggs">
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-offset-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="more_orders_btn">Add More Orders + </button>
    </div>                  
    <h4 class="text-center" id="form_subhead">Name, Address and Mobile number fields are compulsory</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="client_name" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
       <div class="col-md-8">
           <input type="text" class="form-control client_name" name="client_name" placeholder="Full names of client">
       </div>
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="client_add" class="col-md-2 control-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="client_add" placeholder="Full Address" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mobile" class="col-md-2 control-label">Mobile No</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile No">
        </div>
        <label for="phone" class="col-md-2 control-label">Phone No</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone No">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="order_submit">Submit Order</button>&nbsp&nbsp
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" name="order_cancel">Cancel Order</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

jquery:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form button#more_orders_btn').on("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var moreOrders = '';
                moreOrders += '<div class="new_order">';
                moreOrders += '<div class="form-group">';
                moreOrders += '<label for="type" class="col-md-2 control-label">Type</label>';
                moreOrders += '<div class="col-md-6">';
                moreOrders += '<select name="type[]" class="form-control type">';
                moreOrders += '<option value="">-- Select Type of Eggs --</option>';
                moreOrders += '<option value="wsmall">White Small (N550 per crate)</option>';
                moreOrders += '<option value="wmedium">White Medium (N620 per crate)</option>';
                moreOrders += '<option value="wbig">White Big (N680 per crate)</option>';
                moreOrders += '<option value="wjumbo">White Jumbo (N750 per crate)</option>';
                moreOrders += '<option value="bsmall">Brown Small (N530 per crate)</option>';
                moreOrders += '<option value="bmedium">Brown Medium (N600 per crate)</option>';
                moreOrders += '<option value="bbig">Brown Big (N650 per crate)</option>';
                moreOrders += '<option value="bjumbo">Brown Jumbo (N700 per crate)</option>';
                moreOrders += '</select>';
                moreOrders += '</div>';
                moreOrders += '</div>';
                moreOrders += '<div class="form-group">';
                moreOrders += '<label for="quant" class="col-md-2 control-label">Quantity(Crates)</label>';
                moreOrders += '<div class="col-md-6">';
                moreOrders += '<input type="text" class="form-control quant" name="quant[]" placeholder="Quantity of eggs">';
                moreOrders += '</div>';
                moreOrders += '&nbsp&nbsp<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="canc_orders_btn"> X </button>';
                moreOrders += '</div></div><br/>';
                $('form#order_eggs').prepend(moreOrders);
   });
```

Comment: thanks @Mihai. How do i go about making the field names dynamic without adding [ ] after the field names?

Comment: The code is working fine for me @Flexi
Did you tried `var_dump($_POST);` ?

Comment: Thanks @Deepak. I just tried var_dump now and was surprised it displayed all my fields. but when i tried to display them with echo only one gets returned.Why could this be?